# Objective-C, iOS SDK, NSMutableArray, add elements and save data

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

Basically, every time I enter something in my textfield and save it to the table, the previous entry will be replaced by the new one. How do I add elements in a mutable array and save the last entry? I tried

```
[tabledata addObject....
```

and in the entry

```
tabledata.lastObject objectAtIndex...
```

but that didn't work.

here is what I have:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    titlestring = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"titlehomework" ];
    detailsstring = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"detailshomework"];

    tabledata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:titlestring, nil];

    tablesubtitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:detailsstring, nil];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return [tabledata count];
}


-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath;
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle   reuseIdentifier:@"homeworkcell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [tablesubtitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [ UIColor clearColor ];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //-----------------------------------------START----------------------------Set image of   cell----
    cellImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxblank.png"];
    cell.imageView.image = cellImage;
   //--------------------------------------------END---------------------------end set image of cell--  

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You need to post the code where you are attempting to add objects to the `tabledata` array.

Comment: What do you mean by *"save the last entry"* in *"How do I add elements in a mutable array and save the last entry"*? Can you post the code where you try to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code, the best I can do is suggest something like this

```
[tabledata addObject:newTitle];
[tablesubtitles addObject:newSubtitle];
[tableView reloadData];
```

This assumes both `newTitle` and `newSubtitle` are the `NSString`s you wish to add and that `tableView` is the pointer to the `UITableView`.

Comment: makes sense, now, how do I call it in here: `cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` I can't use just tabledata